# android studio 1.2 logcat window animation slow

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat

I've just updated Android Studio to 1.2 and they have added some stupid animation to opening and closing Logcat tab. Adb gets clear every open and close( I have checked the Tools-> Androdi -> Enable ADB integration) also it is very very slow opening and closing of the tab and it gets stuck at some point. Is there a way to stop the animations?

Comment: Thanks god i didn't updated mine :D

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your background process of your PC
2. Check your pc memory & CPU http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Comment: I did not have any problems before the update, so I do not think it is PC related